# How to install Nvidia 610M graphic card in Thinkpad Edge E430 w/ Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, thinkpad

How I can install NVidia 610M graphic card drivers in a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E430 with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: The Edge E430 is the model name for your Lenovo Thinkpad 3254A59 which has a 2.5GHz i5-2520M CPU, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, 1GB NVIDIA GeForce 610M, CDRW/DVDRW, 802.11bgn wireless, and 1Gb Ethernet,  Your hardware manual is at https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/e430_e430c_e435_hmm_en_0b48438_03.pdf  and user guide is at https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/e430_e430c_e435_e530_e530c_e535_ug_en.pdf . The Intel GPU that's built into the CPU has drivers built in to the Linux kernel. All you need to do is install drivers for the NVIDIA 610M alternate graphics adapter.

Comment: Searching to find the exact model name "3254A59" was the most important step. Then, searching the Lenovo support website showed me what was in the laptop, the second important steps. Then, a search on the graphics manufacturer website showed me what the drivers is and how to install it. Google is your friend today.

Answer (score 0):

Download your NVIDIA 610M drivers from https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/104284/ which also includes your installation instructions.

Once you have downloaded the driver, change to the directory containing the driver package, make it executable with `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run` ,  and install the driver by running `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run`

One of the last installation steps will offer to update your X configuration file. Either accept that offer, edit your X configuration file manually so that the NVIDIA X driver will be used, or run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`  .